# How can I check if the current request is from htmx

Tags: django, htmx

I'm using Django, Is there a way to check if the current request is from HTMX

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check for `HX-Request` in the request headers, as mentioned in another answer. Or you can use the [HTMX Django extension](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx) and simply check if `request.htmx` is `True`.

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: @AlexZ I think it is unnecessary to use third party library to just check for htmx request when you can do it with django request itself no need of any other tool use `HTTP_HX_REQUEST` as i explained in my answer.

Comment: @Ahtisham you are correct, but the third party library offers other features like integrating HTMX responses with the Django debugger, which can be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the server-side solution you use, you can look for the `HX-Request` header. It will be set to `true` in all htmx requests. More information can be found here https://htmx.org/docs/#request-header

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this in Django by using `HTTP_HX_REQUEST` of `request.META` like this:

```
def myview(request):
   if request.META.get('HTTP_HX_REQUEST'):
      print("HTMX is available")
   else:
      print("HTMX is not available")
```